# From live site to localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been asked to clone a live site locally.

I have everything set up and it works entirely, except links are incorrect, I have changed their `.htaccess` a bit:

My root URL is:

```
localhost/httpdocs
```

When I go to:

```
localhost/httpdocs?path=homepage_video
```

For example, it successfully goes to the homepage video.

However, all links are already set as such:

```
localhost/httpdocs/homepage_video
```

I would like these links to work as well.

My `.htaccess` is as such:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?path=$1 [L,QSA]

AddType text/x-component .htc
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Which obviously isn't working for me, on the homepage `localhost/httpdocs`, everything IS working (all images and everything link correctly and everything looks good), but clicking on links from then out won't work (because it isn't going correctly to `?path=homepage_video` if it's `/homepage_video`).

Comment: That still does't work -- images also still work for it (it is stored how you assumed) -- but `httpdocs/why` still doesn't successfully lead to `httpdocs?path=why` (or any other link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rewrite rule to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /httpdocs/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^/]+)/?$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

***EDIT** : (How this regex works?)*

This matches all the nested directories:

`[^/]+/` = `[^/]` Anything but not `/`; `+` One or more times; `/` followed by a slash

`([^/]+/)*` = `(..)*` Match what's inside `()` repeatedly, `*` zero or more times

This matches the last URL directory:

`<nested-dir-regex>[^/]+` = Anything but not `/`; one or more times `+`

`(<nested-dir-regex>[^/]+)` = With `()` around it can be captured as `$1` now

`(<nested-dir-regex>[^/]+)/?` = Optionally, followed by last `/`; matches `?` zero or one

`^(<nested-dir-regex>[^/]+)/?$` = `^` denotes start of path string; `$` denotes end of path string

Comment: `RewriteRule ^httpdocs/([^/]+)/?$ httpdocs?path=$1 [L,QSA]` isn't working either =/ still same scenario (URL not found if I do that, but foudn if i just do `?path=`)

Comment: Do you have an `index.php` inside `httpdocs`? Who receives path when you pass it as `?path=`? Do you have any other htaccess file like at the root directory and inside httpdocs as well?

Comment: Yes index.php is inside httpdocs -- .htaccess is found inside httpdocs -- and I'm not sure what you mean by who receives path.  That may be the issue though -- on the livesite, it is `example.com/index.php?path=why` that redirects correctly -- and `example.com/why` goes to the same thing... Apologies for my confusion.  I am poor with htaccess

Comment: EDIT: Actually, it doesn't entirely work-- it fails on links that go multiple deep, e.g.: `example.com/httpdocs/why` works but `example.com/httpdocs/why/why2` fails -- whereas /httpdocs?path=why/why2 works... Any idea??

Ack, you are a hero.  Thank you very much.  Perhaps you could explain to me a little bit? :) I can comprehend WHY it should be rewritebase and WHY it should still have index.php, but especially the regex part confuses me... I am unable to find a very good comprehensive link on .htaccess stuff :/

Comment: @Paul, use `^(([^/]+/)*[^/]+)/?$` to take care of nested directories as well.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much, that was enormously helpful!